# Qinggong - Which Monk ability do I have to give up to take Ki Powers?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monk, archetype

From the [**PRD**](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateMagic/spellcastingClassOptions/monk.html):

> **Ki Power:** A qinggong monk can select a ki power (see below) for which she qualifies in place of the following monk class abilities: slow fall (4th), high jump (5th), wholeness of body (7th), diamond body (11th), abundant step (12th), diamond soul (13th), quivering palm (15th), timeless body (17th), tongue of the sun and moon (17th), empty body (19th), and perfect self (20th). This replaces the monk class ability the qinggong monk gives up for this ki power.

I don't understand which ability you have to give up to select a Ki Power. The only detail is **"for which she qualifies"** and it is about the Ki Power, not about the ability you have to give up.

- Can I take **Deny Death** (4th-level Ki Power) by giving up **Perfect Self** (20th-level monk ability) ? This seems useless but if the campaign stops at level 7, it's a free ki power...
- Can I take **Blinding Critical** (20th-level Ki Power) by giving up **Slow Fall** (4th-level monk ability) ? This seems unbalanced, but RAW I don't see what prevents it.

There are 6th-level Ki Power but no 6th-level monk ability to give up. Same for level 16. Which monk ability can I give up to take **Remove Disease** (6th-level Ki Power) ? What about if I want to take **Bleeding Critical** (16th-level Ki Power) ?

It may look like multiple questions, but they are all part of the same Qinggong mechanic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The important line of the [qinggong](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/monk/archetypes/paizo-monk-archetypes/qinggong-monk/) [monk](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/monk/) archetype's special ability *ki* power says, "This replaces the monk class ability the qinggong monk gives up for this *ki* power." This is later clarified by the section on Requirements that says, "All *ki* powers have a *minimum* monk level requirement to select them. A monk who does not meet this requirement cannot select that *ki* power" (emphasis mine).

This means such a monk can give up the level 20 monk special ability [perfect self](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/monk/#TOC-Perfect-Self-) for the *ki* power [deny death](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/deny-death/), but the monk won't actually *get* the *ki* power deny death until level 20 when the monk would normally get the special ability perfect self.

This also means a less-than-level-20 monk *can't* give up the level 4 monk special ability [slow fall](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/monk/#TOC-Slow-Fall-Ex-) for the level 20 ki power [blinding critical](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/blinding-critical-combat-critical/) because the *ki* power blinding critical has as a requirement being a level 20 monk.

Further, there's no way to delay or swap a monk special abilities for *ki* powers *after* having advanced a level. That is, the monk couldn't opt to take *neither* slow fall *nor* a minimum-level-4 *ki* power so as to leave that level empty for a higher-level trade later on. A monk can't opt to take *nothing* so as to later fill that empty low-level monk ability with high-level awesome.

To take a ki power that requires being a level 6 monk, the monk trades a higher-than-level-6 monk special ability for the minimum-monk-level-6 *ki* power. For example, the monk can trade the level 7 monk special ability [wholeness of body](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/monk/#TOC-Wholeness-of-Body-Su-) for the minimum-monk-level-6 *ki* power *remove disease*.

Comment: In your last paragraph example, does the monk make the choice of swapping *wholeness of body* for *remove disease* at level 6, or at level 7 ? In any case, if I understood your answer correctly, he actually gets *remove disease* at level 7, right ?

Comment: @Kalissar The monk *can't* make the choice to swap out wholeness of body until the monk *has* wholeness of body. So, yes, he'd get a *ki* power that has a minimum monk level of 6 at monk level 7 if he trades out wholeness of body.